# If audio file in pause action How to play audio file from the begining

Tags: javascript, jquery

If audio file in pause action How to play audio file from the begining using jquery

Here is my code

```
<audio id="beep-one" controls="controls" preload="auto">
<source src="test.ogg"></source>
Your browser isn't invited for super fun time.
</audio>
<a href="#" class="track1"  >click here</a>
<a href="#" class="track2"  >click here</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".track2").hide();
    $(".track1").click(function(){
    var beepOne = $("#beep-one")[0];
    $(".track1").hide();
    $(".track2").show();
    beepOne.play();
    });
    $(".track2").click(function(){
    var beepOne = $("#beep-one")[0];
    $(".track1").show();
    $(".track2").hide();
    beepOne.pause();
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Instead of pausing it why don't you just stop it? Then starting it again should go from the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply reset the time of the `Audio` object using `Audio.prototype.currentTime`. All you have to do is:

```
beepOne.currentTime = 0; // the time unit used here is seconds!
```

And the time will reset to 0. However, you cannot access the `currentTime` property before the audio is fully downloaded by the browser, so you should only access it after the `beepOne.canplaythrough` event has fired.

A `DOM Exception 8` will be thrown if you try to loop through the audio before it's completely downloaded.

Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video).

Answer (score 0):

try the below code,
Its like replacing with new source. Hope, it will work.

```
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = "test.ogg";
```